# How to get gdb to stop at breakpoints in code executed via check?

Tags: gdb

How do I get gdb to stop at a breakpoint in code that is executed via check?

```
#include<check>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Suite *s = create_suite(); //create a test suite
    SRunner *sr = srunner_create(s);
    srunner_run_all(sr, CK_NORMAL); 
}
```

Somewhere in `srunner_run_all(sr, CK_NORMAL)` my code gets executed. I can set breakpoints within that code (it's a shared library which is no problem thanks to pending breakpoints). Once the shared library was loaded, `info b` prints the breakpoint correctly. Nevertheless, gdb doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

Edit: If I set a breakpoint within the code snipped above, gdb does stop though.

Comment: Did you try if setting a hbreak behaves differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `srunner_run_all(sr, CK_NOFORK);` did the trick. Check forks a new process for the tests, so that seg-faults etc. can be handled and reported without the test program to crash.

More details can be found in the [documentation of check](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_4.html)

Comment: You could also follow forks with gdb (see http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Forks)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by doing :

```
srunner_set_fork_status(sr, CK_NOFORK);
srunner_run_all(sr, CK_NORMAL);
```